# Python: Repeatedly Nested Loops - How to stack them correctly

Tags: python, list, export-to-csv, nested-lists

Sorry if it's a trivial question, I'm pretty new to Python.
I have the following schematic list of lists (of lists) which needs to be partially flattened (in order to be saved in a csv):

```
[[Header1, Header2,....,Header9,  Header10(a),  Header10(b), ...., Header20],
 [item1,   item2,...,    item9,   item 10a,     item10b ,...,      item 20],
 [......],
 [item1,   item2,...,   item9, [i10a, i10a, i10a], [i10b,i10b, i10b], item20],
 [item1,   item2,...,   item9, [i10a, i10a],       [i10b,i10b],       item20],
 [......]]
```

i.e. I have a few lists where items 10a and 10b are lists themselves (because they are (arbitrarily) repeated elements within item10 itself).

The outer/full list is supposed to end up in a csv file.
The way I want the output to look like is that the lists themselves are regular rows. And the nested list elements turn into own rows as well:

```
 Header1   Header2    ....   Header10a  Header10b  .... Header20
  Item1     Item2     ....     Item10a   Item10b   .... Item20
   ...       ...      ....       ...       ...     ....  ...
  Item1     Item2     ....     Item10a   Item10b   .... Item20
                               Item10a   Item10b
                               Item10a   Item10b   
  Item1     Item2     ....     Item10a   Item10b   .... Item20
                               Item10a   Item10b 
   ...       ...      ....       ...       ...     ....   ...
```

I've been experimenting with while loops (using a further variable that counts these gaps) to get this irregular structure, but I seem to lack some additional knowledge/experience to actually get the desired result.

Hence, me asking for help.

**Edit**
**(Update):**
The answer/easiest solution was in the end to use the full list of lists (of lists) from above and transfer this into a new list of lists. By telling each element its new position in the new list of lists, one can achieve the desired flattening in the same sense as presented in the schematic table shown above. (Iterate through the inside of the deepest nested lists and let the position in the new list be changed by the iterator, e.g. NewList[i-j].append(..) with j being said iterator.)

Comment: Are the rows corresponding to the inner-inner lists suppose to include everything from the row?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: The inner-inner list rows are supposed to not include the other items in the same rows (or at least not the repeating elements). So that it’s later possible to map them with the bigger item surrounding these repeated inner-inner lists

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? What have you tried with while loops?

Comment: @ElliotWay     I've edited the post, I hope it's better now :)

Comment: That's a lot of relevant information, but unfortunately I'm still not quite able to follow. Can you check that the "Item 32 Size" code is right? You're missing some indentation, and you refer to "i" and "j" loops, but there's only a loop over "m" there. Also, a lot of your variable names are confusing - what does "jj" mean?

Comment: Sorry, the item 32 size missed all the indentations, yes! The "i" and "j" loops are second and third code boxes of the EDIT part. I've also further cleaned these ones a bit to make them (hopefully) easier to read. 
The jj was a residual of a mental support for myself, sorry.
I also added more information following up the "m" loop (i.e. where it is actually supposed to appear in the entire code).
t_ident is my way of saying "table_identifier" and things like tr or str are "table row" (from HTML) or "string". :)